# Proof in metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm at the beginning of learning metric spaces and I've been given a fundamental problem.

> Let $\left ( X,d \right )$ is metric space. Let $Y\subset X$. For
>   $x,y\in Y$ we put $d^{*}\left ( x,y \right )=d\left ( x,y \right )$.
>   Prove that function $d^{*}:YxY\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is metric on Y.

My solution:
I need to verify three metric properties:

1. $d(x,y)\geqslant 0,\hspace{0.2cm} \forall x,y\in X\hspace{0.2cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.2cm}d(x,y)=0\hspace{0.2cm}\text{iff} \hspace{0.2cm}x=y\\$
2. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)\hspace{0.1cm}(\text{symmetry})\hspace{0.2cm} \forall x,y\in X\\$
3. $d(x,y)=d(y,x)\hspace{0.1cm}(\text{symmetry})\hspace{0.2cm} \forall x,y\in X\\$

We can see that it verifies the second condition since $d\left ( x,y \right )=d\left ( y,x \right )=d^{*}\left ( x,y \right )=d^{*}\left ( y,x \right )$.

But how should I verify the first and the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd property should be the triangle inequality.

The proof for $d^\ast$ is trivial, because $d$ obeys all these properties, which are universal statements so they still hold when specialised to the subset $Y$.

Comment: When $Y\subseteqq X$, Y obeys all of the properties X, so does the triangle inequality, But how should I write it?

Comment: @MartinN. Take any $x,y,z \in Y$, then in particular $x,y,z \in X$ so $d^\ast(x,z) = d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(x,z) = d^\ast(x,y) + d^\ast(y,z)$, where the $\le$ comes from $d$ obeying the triangle inequality on $X$ and the rest is true by definition.

Comment: Okay, thank you